# Функция Button Reset в HTML не работает

Tags: html, css, css3, html-form

Кнопка сброса отзыва не работает на блоках Имя, Фамилия, Отчество и email

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Пример</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div> <a href="lab7.html">Вернуться на главную</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <legend style="font-size: 30px">Гостевая книга</legend><br>
    <legend>Имя:</legend>
    <p><input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName"></p>
    <legend>Фамилия:</legend>
    <p><input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName"></p>
    <legend>Отчество:</legend>
    <p><input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName"></p>
    <legend>E-mail:</legend>
    <p><input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName"></p>
    <hr>
    <legend>Ваш город:</legend>
    <br>
    <select size="5">
      <option>Москва</option>
      <option> Санкт-Петербург</option>
      <option> Вологда</option>
      <option>Ярославль</option>
      <option>Архангельск</option>
      <option>Северодвинск</option>
      <option>Новодвинск</option>
      <option>Мурманск</option>
      <option>Астрахань</option>
      <option>Ташкент</option>
      <option>Иркутск</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <hr>
    <legend>Как бы Вы оценили качество обслуживания?</legend>
    <form>
      <p><input type="radio" name="Name">1★</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="Name">2★</p>
      <p><input type=radio name="Name">3★</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="Name">4★</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="Name">5★</p>
      <hr>
      <legend>Что Вам понравилось у нас больше всего?</legend>
      <form>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="Name">Обслуживание<input type="checkbox" name="Name">Чистота <input type="checkbox" name="Name">Комфорт</p>
        <legend>Комментарий:</legend>
        <textarea name=Proba2 wrap=off cols=30 rows=3>
</textarea><br><br>
        <style>
          h1 {
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgb(119, 136, 153);
          }
          
          p {
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: rgb(119, 136, 153);
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font-family: cursive;
          }
          
          legend {
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: rgb(119, 136, 153);
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font-family: cursive;
          }
          
          button {
            background-color: rgb(119, 136, 153);
          }
        </style>

        <br><br> Отправить отзыв?
        <form>
          <p><input type="button" onClick='alert("Отзыв отправлен")' value="Отправить"><input type="reset" value="Сброс"></p>
        </form>

        <body>
          <html>
```

Comment: Сброс работает только на поля формы. У тебя в форме вообще нет полей...

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь советую над форматом кода по работать, посмотреть как вообще другие мини проекты строятся. Ошибка была в том что вы несколько раз обернули объекты на форму.

```html
<div> <a href="lab7.html">Вернуться на главную</a>
    <form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <legend style="font-size: 30px">Гостевая книга</legend><br>
        <legend>Имя:</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName">
        </p>
        <legend>Фамилия:</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName">
        </p>
        <legend>Отчество:</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName">
        </p>
        <legend>E-mail:</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="text" size="50" maxlenght="45" name="mainName">
        </p>
        <hr>
        <legend>Ваш город:</legend>
        <br>
        <select size="5">
            <option>Москва</option>
            <option> Санкт-Петербург</option>
            <option> Вологда</option>
            <option>Ярославль</option>
            <option>Архангельск</option>
            <option>Северодвинск</option>
            <option>Новодвинск</option>
            <option>Мурманск</option>
            <option>Астрахань</option>
            <option>Ташкент</option>
            <option>Иркутск</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <hr>
        <legend>Как бы Вы оценили качество обслуживания?</legend>
        <p><input type="radio" name="Name">1★</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="Name">2★</p>
        <p><input type=radio name="Name">3★</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="Name">4★</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="Name">5★</p>
        <hr>
        <legend>Что Вам понравилось у нас больше всего?</legend>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="Name">Обслуживание<input type="checkbox" name="Name">Чистота <input type="checkbox" name="Name">Комфорт</p>
        <legend>Комментарий:</legend>
        <textarea name=Proba2 wrap=off cols=30 rows=3></textarea><br><br>
        <p>
            <input type="button" onClick='alert("Отзыв отправлен")' value="Отправить">
            <input type="reset" value="Сброс">
        </p>
    </form>
```

Рабочий метод, обёрнутый в форму, в коде много ошибок, нужно детально высматривать правильность использования тегов, заметил в конце body не имеет закрывающий тег. Стили нужно выгрузить в отдельный файл .css, либо разместить в самый конец кода.